# unable to push to an within object literal

Tags: jquery, arrays, object-literal

My object literal has an info property with a value that is an array. I'm trying to push new data into that array, using an each function on the object literal to make sure I'm updating the correct goal.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/charliemagee/ZZwnN/

Console shows Uncaught TypeError: Object ['66','77'] has no method 'push'

But the previous console.log shows that it is an array, so push should work, right?

Here's a section of the object literal.

```
goals = {

  "9e693231-e6d8-4ca9-b5c8-81ea7a8dd54": {
    category: "school",
    datecreated: "2013-10-20",
    goal: "keep locker tidy",
    icon: "clipboard",
    status: "inprogress",
    infotype: "text",
    info: "['66','77']",
    recurring: "mon,wed,fri",
    complete: "Great Job!",
    deadline: "2014-1-20",
    username: "maryjones",
    userguid: "0c7270bd-38e8-4db2-ae92-244de019mju7"
  }
}
```

And here's the function that's supposed to push the array.

```
$(".goalsinprogress").delegate("input[type=checkbox]", "click", function() {
  goalguid = $(this).parent().parent().data("goalguid");
  emailGoal = $(this).parent().data('goal');
  newinfo = $(this).closest('li').find('input[type="text"]').val();
  $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("inprogress missed").addClass("completed").prop("checked", true);
  updateStatus = 'completed';
  $.each(goals, function(index, goal) {
    if (index === goalguid) {
      console.log(goal.info); // shows that goal.info is an array
      goal.info.push(newinfo); // gives me the error
      console.log(goal.info);
      goal.status = updateStatus;
      return false;
    }
  });
  localStorage.setItem("goals", JSON.stringify(goals));
  $(this).find('.info').hide();
  $(this).find('.info').val('');
  return displayMyGoalList();
});
```

Comment: in the fiddle `$(this).siblings().children().val();` What are you trying to do?

Comment: damn, my fiddle didn't get updated and I didn't notice. Here's a new version, but now I'm not getting the same error because I'm not at my development machine and the server doesn't have the latest changes. Damn.  http://jsfiddle.net/charliemagee/ZZwnN/7/

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. Here's the correct fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/charliemagee/ZZwnN/9/

Comment: `info: "['66','77']"`, isn't an array, it's a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the console log to `console.log(typeof(goal.info));` you'll see it is a string, not an array. Remove the quotes and it works fine:

```
  "9e693231-e6d8-4ca9-b5c8-81ea7a8dd54": {
    category: "school",
    datecreated: "2013-10-20",
    goal: "keep locker tidy",
    icon: "clipboard",
    status: "inprogress",
    infotype: "text",
    info: ['66','77'],  // no quotes here
    recurring: "mon,wed,fri",
    complete: "Great Job!",
    deadline: "2014-1-20",
    username: "maryjones",
    userguid: "0c7270bd-38e8-4db2-ae92-244de019mju7"
  },
```

Comment: Ah jeez, the one item I was testing with is the one I forgot to take out the quote marks. Thanks @Dom Day and meagar